# Parsing XML from URL and getting info from tag

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree, wms

I try to get info from the tag "CRS" from an XML using python and collect all the CRS tags, or I will later edit the code to check for specific CRS.

Url: https://wms.geonorge.no/skwms1/wms.adm_enheter_historisk?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities

I can get the data, but I can't figure out how to get the info from the correct tag.

This is my code so far:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = 'https://wms.geonorge.no/skwms1/wms.adm_enheter_historisk?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities'
uh = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = uh.read()

tree = ET.fromstring(data)
```

From here I'm not sure how to proceed with the tree.find() or tree.findall()

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? The [documenation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#finding-interesting-elements) has a variety of examples, several of which seem relevant to your question.

Comment: You will want to search for something along the lines of "how to use XML with default namespaces in elementree"

Answer (score 0):

So, here is what I did. I needed to check if the the XML contained the CRS EPSG:3857. So instead of getting all the info in the CRS tag, I worked around the problem with testing if the parsed XML contained the text "EPSG:3857".

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = 'https://wms.geonorge.no/skwms1/wms.adm_enheter_historisk?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities'
uh = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = uh.read()

projection = "EPSG:3857"

if projection in str(data):
    print("Contains")
else:
    print("Contains not")
```

Now implementing in another program to search trough multiple XML files.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
from simplified_scrapy import req, SimplifiedDoc
xml = req.get(
    'https://wms.geonorge.no/skwms1/wms.adm_enheter_historisk?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities'
)
doc = SimplifiedDoc(xml)
listCRS = doc.selects('CRS')
print(listCRS)
```